# Pass increasing index in multiprocessing with Python

Tags: python, indexing, multiprocessing

Let's say I have the following piece of code:

```
items = []
for index, element in elements:
     if index is 7:
         continue
     else:
         items.append(element)
```

I'm using selenium for web scraping in the code so I'd like to make it faster by using multiprocessing.

So it'd be this way:

```
items = pool.map(iterate_over_elements, elements)

def iterate_over_elements(element):
     if index is 7:
        return None
     else:
        return element
```

How can I send the index as a parameter in each call to iterate_over_elements()?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Accessing the index in Python 'for' loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/522563/accessing-the-index-in-python-for-loops)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To add the index, you'll want to use `enumerate`:

```
>>> list(enumerate(['a','b','c']))
[(0, 'a'), (1, 'b'), (2, 'c')]
```

`pool.map(fn, enumerate(elements))` will call `fn` with tuples of `(index, element)`. To accept that, you'll have to change your `iterate_over_elements` function:

```
def iterate_over_elements(index_and_element):
    index, element = index_and_element
    ...
pool.map(iterate_over_elements, enumerate(elements))
```

or, if you have python >= 3.3, you can use `Pool.starmap` and have `iterate_over_elements` accept two arguments:

```
def iterate_over_elements(index, element):
    ...
pool.starmap(iterate_over_elements, enumerate(elements))
```

Comment: what if I wanted to send an additional parameter to each call? Then the function would receive 3 parameters: the list element, its index and the other param.

Comment: I suggest you experiment!